# Можно ли сделать резиновым отображение кол-во слов?

Tags: html, jquery, css, html5, вёрстка

Задача такова, чтобы при изменении размера div (уменьшении) уменьшалось кол-во слов в HTML.

Делаю адаптивку через медиа запросы. В дизайне блок меньше и слов становится меньше. Размер шрифта  и отступы менять не нужно.

Заранее спасибо за отклик.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оберните ваш текст в классы и скрывайте по мере необходимости:

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .hidden-xs {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .hidden-sm {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .hidden-md {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<span> Это показывается всегда</span>
<span class="hidden-xs"> Это скрывается только на самом маленьком разрешении</span>
<span class="hidden-sm"> Это скрывается на планшетах</span>
<span class="hidden-md"> Это скрывается на маленьких мониторах</span>
```